# Custom function throws exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop

So I've been working with lists lately and I'm trying to get a special class to work, so I wrote a for loop to test the basic function, but it just gives me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\nice code\v2.py", line 13, in <module>
    if Lenlist == len.lenList(len.listLen(List=len.list(list=List().list()))): print(Lenlist);
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\nice code\v2.py", line 3, in lenList
    def lenList(self, list=list): return len(list);
TypeError: 'List' object is not callable
```

Here is the source for you:

```
class List:
  List = list('list');
  def lenList(self, list=list): return len(list);
  def listLen(self, List=len): return list(List);
  def lenlist(self, len=list): return self.lenList(list=len);
  def list(self, list=list): return self.List;
  def listlen(self, len=len): return self.list(list=len);
len = List();
Lenlist = 0;
for Len in len.listLen(List=len.list(list=List().list())):
  if Len in list(len.listLen(List=len.list(list=Len))):
    Lenlist += list(len.listLen(List=len.list(list=Len))).count(Len);
    if Lenlist == len.lenList(len.listLen(List=len.list(list=List().list()))): print(Lenlist);
```

What I was expecting was for it to print the length of the List.List. I already tried to replace all of the positional arguments with keywords.

Comment: `len = List()` shadows the builtin function.

Comment: Just wanted to leave this comment here because... _WOW!_. `lenlist`ception. Probably the interpreter was also amazed of how many `len` `list`len` you've used and it scared him a bit

Comment: You might want to consider deriving your class from `list`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some key notes here that you need to follow

1. Always try to avoid overwriting python keyword or pre-defined functions(Eg: len)
2. Do not have variable names inside a class which have same name as class name

1st problem I see is that you have overwritten len in lenList you won;t get your desired output
2nd problem I found in your code is that lenList function is trying to return len(list)
list is a python pre-defined class so len won't be able to find anything

I have changed your code a little bit which now prints 4

```
class List:
  List1 = list('list');
  def lenList(self, list=list): return len(self.List1);
  def listLen(self, List=len): return list(self.List1);
  def lenlist(self, len=list): return self.lenList(list=len);
  def list(self, list=list): return self.List1;
  def listlen(self, len=len): return self.list(list=len);
len1 = List();
Lenlist = 0;

for Len in len1.listLen(List=len1.list(list=List().list())):
  if Len in list(len1.listLen(List=len1.list(list=Len))):
    Lenlist += list(len1.listLen(List=len1.list(list=Len))).count(Len);
    if Lenlist == len1.lenList(len1.listLen(List=len1.list(list=List().list()))): print(Lenlist);
```